# Is there a way to know when angular-svg-round-progressbar has completed its animation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

I'd like to use angular-svg-round-progressbar as a sort of onMouseDown timer such that a function doesn't execute until the progressbar has completed its animation to its new "current" value.  The on-render option appears to fire when the svg itself is rendered, which is not what I'm looking for in this case.  Is there a way to call a function when a new "current" value has been set and the animation completes its update to the new value?

Here's my current html:

```
<div class="progress-wrapper">
  <a href="#/track"
      class="button padding homebutton"
      ng-click="onClickFunction(type.id)"
      ng-mousedown="startButton(type.id)"
      ng-repeat="type in types">

    <div class="progress ng-cloak top-center">
      <i class="icon {{type.icon}}"></i>
      <br/>{{type.title}}
    </div>
    <round-progress
      max="10"
      current="type.pressed"
      color="#45ccce"
      bgcolor="#eaeaea"
      radius="55"
      stroke="12"
      semi="false"
      rounded="false"
      clockwise="true"
      responsive="false"
      duration="1800"
      animation="easeInOutQuart"
      on-render="buttonOnRender(progress, options, root)"
      animation-delay="0"></round-progress>
  </a>
</div>
```

This produces a nice button with an icon and text in the middle and I can easily prompt some action when the button is pressed.  But what I want to do is delay that action until after the animation as completed.

Thanks for your ideas.

UPDATE: So I suppose one work-around could be to still trigger off of ng-click or ng-mousedown but then delay within one of those functions for the "duration" value, but that doesn't seem very clean to me.